# NodeJs Eventqueue's in Cluster

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js, When multiple processes are created using Cluster, do all of them have individual event loop or do they share the event loop? The doubt is because of

> Note: Note that even though a global thread pool which is shared across all events loops is used, the functions are not thread safe.

at the link

http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html#threadpool

Which indicates multiple event loops in nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libuv is a separate project that is used by more than just node.js, so the documentation snippet you posted is speaking more generally and not referring to a specific user of libuv. Each node.js process currently has only one (individual) event loop.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the clarification. As i understand now, Every process forked using cluster would have its own event loop, so n forks will result in n even loop.